# Try if Statement Breaks my print str

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, try-catch

I'm trying to make it so if the user enters in any letters it won't give any errors. It will just restart the program.

```
x = int(input())
try:
    if x == (a, b, c): # Entering letters in the x integer will restart the program.
        displayStart()
        return
print('')
```

I have this, The print statement at the bottom becomes an invalid syntax after i've entered this "try:" Statement. Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: You need `except` block after `try`

Comment: A tutorial on python exceptions looks needed.

Comment: you should [learn python the hard way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/).

Comment: Be sure to choose an answer that best helps :)

Answer (score 0):

`try` suites need to have an `except` and/or `finally` clause.  You have neither.  e.g.

```
try:
    do_something()
except SomeExceptionName:
    do_something_because_some_exception_name_was_raised_in_do_something()
```

Or:

```
try:
    do_something()
finally:
    do_something_even_if_exception_was_raised()
```

You also might want to have a look at the [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html).

If you think about it, what should your `try` suite do here?  If an exception is raised, what would happen differently than normal if you have no way of handling it (via `except`) or cleanup action to perform (via `finally`)?

---

From the python [grammer specification](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/grammar.html):

```
try_stmt: ('try' ':' suite
           ((except_clause ':' suite)+
            ['else' ':' suite]
            ['finally' ':' suite] |
           'finally' ':' suite))
```

Comment: If OP doesn't know how to use a try/except, I doubt he will understand what you just pasted.

Comment: @Paco -- probably not, but the reference is there.  It's not _too_ hard to understand . . .There's `try`, then a suite of commands, then and except clause with more commands, optional else and finally, OR there's a finally.  Anyway, I explained it in words pretty clearly in the first sentence (I think . . .)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an except portion to your try statement. Like this:

```
x = int(input())
try:
    if x == (a, b, c):
        displayStart()
        return
except Exception as e:
    print('An exception occurred: ', e)

print('')
```

A try needs to have its corresponding except.
As a note, it is not very good practice to catch ALL exceptions like I do. Instead of Exception, usually you would specify the particular exception you expect. For example, if I am expecting a ValueError, I would make it:

```
try:
    ...
except ValueError as ve:
    print('A Value Error occurred: ', ve)
```

Also, you usually want to put as little code in the try-except block as possible.

Comment: These days, the syntax `except Exception as e` is preferred I think.

Comment: I tried the first suggestion you posted. And i received an invalid syntax on the comma after "Exception".

Comment: Here, changed it to use @mgilson 's recommendation. Try changing it to `except Exception as e:`

Comment: "These days" is 01-Oct-2008, the release date of Python 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a try statement:

```
try:
   print("this will actually print, because its trying to execute the statements in the tryblock")
   assert(1==0) #a blatently false statement that will throw exception
   print("This will never print, because once it gets to the assert statement, it will throw an exception")
except:
   print("after exception this is printed , because the assert line threw an exception")
```

IF the assert sttement had been `assert(1==1)` it would have never thrown an exception, then it would have printed the "This will never print" line, and NOT the "after exception" line

Of course there are more things involved like `finally` and `else`, but this `try:` `except:` example should be enough to get you started